# React Native - WheelPicker : Invariant violation. Native component for 'WheelCurvedPicker' doesnot exist

Tags: javascript, android-layout, react-native, picker

Installed WheelPicker by the following code

```
npm i react-native-wheel-picker --save
```

Added the following in settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-wheel-picker'
project(':react-native-wheel-picker').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../node_modules/react-native-wheel-picker/android')
```

Added the following in app/build.gradle

```
compile project(':react-native-wheel-picker')
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';


import Picker from 'react-native-wheel-picker'
var PickerItem = Picker.Item;

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedItem : 2,
            itemList: ['刘备', '张飞', '关羽', '赵云', '黄忠', '马超', '魏延', '诸葛亮']
        };
    }

    onPickerSelect (index) {
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: index,
        })
    }

    onAddItem = () => {
        var name = '司马懿'
        if (this.state.itemList.indexOf(name) == -1) {
            this.state.itemList.push(name)
        }
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: this.state.itemList.indexOf(name),
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Welcome to React Native!
                </Text>
                <Picker style={{width: 150, height: 180}}
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedItem}
                    itemStyle={{color:"white", fontSize:26}}
                    onValueChange={(index) => this.onPickerSelect(index)}>
                        {this.state.itemList.map((value, i) => (
                            <PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={"money"+value}/>
                        ))}
                </Picker>
                <Text style={{margin: 20, color: '#ffffff'}}>
                    你最喜欢的是：{this.state.itemList[this.state.selectedItem]}
                </Text>

                <Text style={{margin: 20, color: '#ffffff'}}
                        onPress={this.onAddItem}>
            怎么没有司马懿？
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#1962dd',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
        color: '#ffffff',
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});
```

I am getting an Error as below:

> Invariant Violation: Native component for "WheelCurvedPicker" does not
>   exist
>
> This error is located at:
>       in Item (at App.js:48)
>       in WheelCurvedPicker (at WheelCurvedPicker.android.js:89)
>       in WheelCurvedPicker (at App.js:43)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at App.js:39)
>       in App (at renderApplication.js:33)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32) getViewConfig
>       requireNativeComponent.js:107:6 get$1
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14131:17 createInstance
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14295:27 completeWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10097:14 completeUnitOfWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12769:10 performUnitOfWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12941:32 workLoop
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12953:43 renderRoot
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12996:17 performWorkOnRoot
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13632:34 performWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13545:26 performSyncWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13506:16 requestWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13392:6 scheduleWorkImpl
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13259:24 scheduleWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13207:28 scheduleRootUpdate
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13930:17
>   _updateContainerAtExpirationTime
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13966:6 updateContainer
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13991:8 render
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14726:35 renderApplication
>       renderApplication.js:49:21 run
>       AppRegistry.js:102:10 runApplication
>       AppRegistry.js:194:26
>   __callFunction
>       MessageQueue.js:351:47 
>       MessageQueue.js:116:26
>   __guardSafe
>       MessageQueue.js:314:6 callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       MessageQueue.js:115:17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to incomplete compilation of the project or the project has not been setup correctly.

Based on the installation steps provided by the [**library**](https://github.com/lesliesam/react-native-wheel-picker) and *you in the above question*, i think you forgot to use the package.

**Modify MainApplication**

```
 import com.zyu.ReactNativeWheelPickerPackage;
    ......

    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(), new ReactNativeWheelPickerPackage()
        );
    }
```

*Rebuild and run after this*

Answer (score 0):

The manual linking of WheelPicker in react native comes with these steps

add the following lines into their specific files:

**settings.gradle** : 
**path**: gradle/setting.gradel

```
include ':react-native-wheel-picker-android'
project(':react-native-wheel-picker-android').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-wheel-picker-android/android')
```

**build.gradle** :  
**path**: app/build.gradel

```
implementation project(':react-native-wheel-picker-android')
```

**MainApplication.java** : 
**path**: app/src/main/java/MainApplication.java

in your  List getPackages() method, add the following line just after new MainReactPackage(): new WheelPickerPackage()
so your method should look like this:

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      // Returning the Packages this way is better than calling the getPackages that was here
      //by default which overridden my FbModule
      return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
              new WheelPickerPackage()
      ));
    }
```

and then it should work